# float div cross browser. Every other browser seem okay except 1

Tags: css, ipad

I realy need your help as this is driving me nuts.

On my website [www.markett.nl](http://www.markett.nl) I have 2 divs floating next to eachother.

All the browsers seem to load nicely, accapt when I view the website on the iPad the div is pushed downwards as if its wide is to large.

I have read it mayby has to do with some css padding issues, but I believe padding is not used on these div elements. I use firebug for insight in css but cant solve my problem.

**I've uploaded 2 images so you can see what the probem is:**

[Image 1 as is loads on most browsers.](http://imageshack.us/f/338/img1mu.jpg/)

[Image2 will show the problem.](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/843/img2ra.jpg/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `@media` queries in your CSS file for responsive layout. Find this in your CSS (around line 2640):

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    /* Simplify the basic layout */
    #main #content {
        margin: 0 7.6%;
        width: auto;
    }
```

and remove the `margin` attribute from that rule. Also you don't have to test on iPad the result - you can simply change the width of your browser window.

Comment: THANK YOU. this was the problem. Thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

You're using [media queries](http://mediaqueri.es/) to do different things depending on the width of the viewport.

If you load your site in any browser (I'm testing with Firefox, for example) and reduce the width of the window enough, the same problem happens.

To fix it, follow Zoltan Toth's instructions.